# For in and Object.keys - es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Shouldn't these two function return the same? For in is giving me ForInStatement is not allowed syntax restriction while Object.keys gives me totally different result. As soon as it return false, why is it looping again?

I want to check if any of the elements in an object is null or empty. As soon as it returns false, why is it still looping in Object.keys? While in ForIn, it return false and the loop stops as soon as the empty element is detected in an object.

For In

```
checkEmpty = (obj) => {
    for (const key in obj) {
      if (obj[key] === null || obj[key] === '') {
        console.log('forIn', obj[key] === null || obj[key] === '');
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Object.keys

```
checkEmpty = (obj) => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
          if (obj[key] === null || obj[key] === '') {
            console.log('forEach', obj[key] === null || obj[key] === '');
            return false;
          }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) return value is ignored, and you can't break the loop like you do in [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). Your case you can use `Array.some()`to return the result as soon as the check fails.

**Note 1**: [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) will return `true` whenever a check returns `true`. [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) will return `true` only if all checks return `true`.

**Note 2**: The idea behind your function seems to be return `true` if there's at least one `null` or `''` value, but your code does the opposite. You can negate the result of my function to get `false` when there's an empty item.

**Note 3**: There is in another difference between [`Array.keys/values/entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) with `Array.forEach()`, and a `for...in` loop. The `for...in` loop will also loop all inherited enumerable properties, while the `Object.x()` methods would only iterate own enumerable properties.

```js
// use object values, I use Object.entries to show the key in the console
const checkHasEmpty = obj => Object.entries(obj).some(([key, value]) => console.log(`key: ${key}`) || value === null || value === '')

console.log(checkHasEmpty({}))

console.log(checkHasEmpty({ a: 1, b: null, c: 3 }))

console.log(checkHasEmpty({ a: '', b: 2 }))

console.log(checkHasEmpty({ a: 1, b: 2, c: null }))
```

Comment: yeahhh it works but my question is if there are 3 elements ,it loops thrice before giving the result. It gives the valid result though. But in For In, if the first element is null, it stops looping after first one. So For In is suitable for checking null value right? But the warning appears saying ForInStatement is not allowed syntax restriction. So I m confused.

Comment: And the answer is use `Array.some()` or `Array.every()` return immediately. I've added a console.log with key as an example.

Answer (score 0):

It seems in the second snippet the mistake is here

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
          if (obj[key] === null || obj[key] === '') {
```

`forEach` will accept argument as `(item,index)` where `item` is the element of  array and `index` is the current index in the array.

So `obj[key]` will try to get the element in the array specified by the key which can also be undefined

Try this replacing `obj[key]` by only `key` or `obj[index]`

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
          if (key === null || key === '') {
```

Comment: share the `obj`

Comment: this.checkEmpty({ 'Date', 'Name', '' })

Comment: @AmritaStha this is not a valid object

Comment: sorry this.checkEmpty({ Date: 'Date', Name: 'Name', Address: '' })